# Next.js I don't want the requests for /_next/data/env/~.json

Tags: next.js

I am using src/middleware.ts for page authorization checks. If the authorization passes, I return `NextResponse.next()`, and if it fails, I return `NextResponse.redirect(url)`.

However, when navigating to a page using `<Link href="/page" />` from next/link, the server always fetches a page HTML in the form of /_next/data/[env]/~.json. The page transition is slow as it waits for the JSON response to complete.

Even in the example below, where I simply use NextResponse.next(), it still requests JSON. How can I prevent this and make the page transition through CSR without fetching JSON?

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/trailing-slash-middleware-issue-forked-pnhncl?file=%2Fmiddleware.ts

I want to perform page transitions quickly, like CSR, without making requests to _next/data/[env]/~.json.